# How to make this list of statements into a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
inp[0][0] = shadow[3][0]
inp[0][3] = shadow[0][0]
inp[3][3] = shadow[0][3]
inp[3][0] = shadow[3][3]
```

I want to turn this code into a for loop, because this is disgusting! I can't figure out how though.

Comment: We need more details on what needs to be mapped. Why is [0][3] assigned from [0][0]?

Comment: please add some more details to your question. explain why you are selecting inp[0][0] = shadow[3][0] not inp[0][0] = shadow[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

You are basically picking two sets of coordinates from the series `(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0)`, in a ring fashion. You can do so by iteration over that series with an index to use for the second point:

```
points = [(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0)]
for index, (x, y) in enumerate(points, -1):
    shadow_x, shadow_y = points[index]
    inp[x][y] = shadow[shadow_x][shadow_y]
```

By giving the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) a starting point of `-1` we create an offset that'll find the right matching point in `points`.

You could also use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
points = [(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0)]
for (x, y), (shadow_x, shadow_y) in zip(points, [points[-1]] + points):
    inp[x][y] = shadow[shadow_x][shadow_y]
```

Pick whichever you feel fits your usecase best.

Demo (replacing the actual assignment with a `print()` statement to show what would be executed):

```
>>> points = [(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0)]
>>> for index, (x, y) in enumerate(points, -1):
...     shadow_x, shadow_y = points[index]
...     print(f"inp[{x}][{y}] = shadow[{shadow_x}][{shadow_y}]")
...
inp[0][0] = shadow[3][0]
inp[0][3] = shadow[0][0]
inp[3][3] = shadow[0][3]
inp[3][0] = shadow[3][3]
>>> for (x, y), (shadow_x, shadow_y) in zip(points, [points[-1]] + points):
...     print(f"inp[{x}][{y}] = shadow[{shadow_x}][{shadow_y}]")
...
inp[0][0] = shadow[3][0]
inp[0][3] = shadow[0][0]
inp[3][3] = shadow[0][3]
inp[3][0] = shadow[3][3]
```